# Building and running a C++17/boost program on RHEL 6

Tags: boost, shared-libraries, libstdc++

There's a collection of C++98 programs being built and run on RHEL 6 using the default tools and boost version 1.6.  The build process uses a set makefiles and shell scripts and runs under a specific account.

I'd like to include in that process a C++17 program using the newer tools available from Developer's Toolset 8 and the latest version of boost.

Question #1: How do I do it without interfering with the other programs that use the default tools.  Converting them to also use the new tools is not an option.

Question #2: After it is built, it needs to run under RHEL 6 as well, but it would use different versions of shared libraries (c++ runtime, boost, etc) from the other programs.  How do I make it load the non-default ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I do it without interfering with the other programs that use the default tools. Converting them to also use the new tools is not an option.

You change the `Makefile` for this program to use different compiler:

```
CC = /path/to/new/gcc
CXX = /path/to/new/g++
... etc.
```

> After it is built, it needs to run under RHEL 6 as well, but it would use different versions of shared libraries (c++ runtime, boost, etc) from the other programs. How do I make it load the non-default ones?

You change the `-rpath` of the new program to point to alternate shared library installation directory

```
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/alternate/installation/lib
```